# How to implement InfoWindow with android map utils library in google maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have created an app where all of my markers have CustomInfoWindow.But number of markers in my app getting bigger and bigger.So i saw about map-utils library and decided to implement it.I wanted to implement the marker clustering property.Before Implementing Marker clustering property i have this code in my app:

```
private void drawMarkerAndLine(ArrayList<StatusData> result) throws Exception{
        try {
            if (result.size() != 0) {
                PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions()
                        .fillColor(0x330000FF)
                        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                        .strokeWidth(3);
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    String status = result.get(i).getStatus();
                    String name = result.get(i).getPersonName();
                    String email = result.get(i).getPersonMail();
                    name += "/" + email;
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(result.get(i).getLatitude());
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(result.get(i).getLongitude());
                    if (status.length() > 20) {
                        status = status.substring(0, 20);
                        status += "...";
                    }
                    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    options.add(ll);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title(name).snippet(status));
                    if (i == 0) {
                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15));
                    }
                }
                map.addPolygon(options);
            }
        }catch ( Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Internet Connection Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Now i wanted to remain all my previous properties of like infowindow click,map.setInfoWindowAdapter and others.Just i want to implement the that when i zoom out markers will be clustered and when zoom in it will show the markers and i can click the infowindow like my previous.I have tried to change my this class but in vain.

```
private void drawMarkerAndLine(ArrayList<StatusData> result) throws Exception{
        try {
            if (result.size() != 0) {
                /*PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions()
                        .fillColor(0x330000FF)
                        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                        .strokeWidth(3);*/
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    String status = result.get(i).getStatus();
                    String name = result.get(i).getPersonName();
                    String email = result.get(i).getPersonMail();
                    name += "/" + email;
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(result.get(i).getLatitude());
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(result.get(i).getLongitude());
                    if (status.length() > 20) {
                        status = status.substring(0, 20);
                        status += "...";
                    }
                    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    //options.add(ll);
                    MyItem item = new MyItem(lat,lng);
                    clusterManager.addItem(item);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title(name).snippet(status));
                    if (i == 0) {
                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15));
                    }
                }
                //map.addPolygon(options);

            }
        }catch ( Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Internet Connection Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I have tried in other activity this and it works for just below code.But when i couldn't implement only the clustering property in my previous code.

```
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map_activity, null, false);

        mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFrag.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446),10));
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(), map);
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);

        drawMarker();

        return v;
    }

    private void drawMarker() {
        double lat = 51.5145160;
        double lng = -0.1270060;

        // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            lat = lat + offset;
            lng = lng + offset;
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }
```

How can i implement this in my previous code with the infowindow click and other unchanged as i don't need any onclick listener in clustermanager?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me get it clear, you are getting the markers clustered but when you click on a marker it does nothing, right?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are wrong there.

1- You dont have to create the marker as before, just adding 'MyItem' to the cluster manager is enough.

2- The marker's title, snippet, position and any data you want to show should be inside of your 'MyItem' class.

So your 'MyItem' class should look somethingk like this:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem{
private final LatLng position;
private final String status;
private final String name;
private final String email;

public MyItem(LatLng position2, String status2, String name2, String email2) {

    position = position2;
    status = status2;
    name = name2;
    email = email2;

}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
}
```

Then in you activity create the items like

```
clusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(......));
```

And finally in the class where you extend DefaultClusterRenderer< MyItem >

```
 @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

markerOptions.position(item.getPosition()).title(item.getName()).snippet(item.getStatus);

}
```

and you would get the same as before.

If you want to create a custom info window it gets a little bit more complicated.

Comment: my infowindow is custom..what should i do then??

Comment: Have you already tried to make a custom info window? Show me some code and I will help you to implement the ClusterManager.